# one-to-many to many-to-many Relationship in Django model

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, many-to-many

I am looking for a relationship that

1. A user creates an incident,
2. Select multiple types
3. And every type has many subtypes that users select from front-end

I have a table called the incident,

```
Incident 

name - XYZ
type - Multiple types
subtype - Multiple subtypes 

* Note
A type has many subtypes in the system
```

I am trying to do the below,

```
Incident
name -
type - M2M(Type)

Type
name -
subtype - M2M(Subtype)

Subtype
Name -
```

Please suggest if the below design is good to go. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can design like the following. Here the `Incident` model can have the relations with `SubType` model because you can get the `Type` from the `SubType` model.

```
class Type(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)

class SubType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    type = models.ForeignKey(Type, related_name = "sub_types", on_delete = models.CASCADE)

class Incident(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    sub_types = models.ManyToManyField(SubType)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = "incidents", on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Looks great! Will this serve as an incident select multiple types?

Comment: As I explained, it's enough to take only `sub_types` because each `sub_type` has its parent, `type`. And `type` points to the `Type` model.

Comment: Incident has many `sub_types`, so of course it can have many `types`

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: How developer gonna save the data? When the user sends the incident, types, and subtypes as a developer I should first create records for all the types, then all the subtypes with foreign key type, and then the incident with m2m subtypes.

Comment: What data do you want to save?

Comment: User Data :

incident_name = 'Test Incident',   
incident_types_subtypes = {
'Type 1':['Subtype 1', 'Subtype 2']
'Type 2' : ['Subtype 3', 'Subtype 4']
}